# Can not find required columns: sku in magento

Tags: magento

I want to import products to another store 
so when I want I find this error 
"Can not find required columns: sku"
the csv file already encouded at UTF-8

I spent all the day searching but with no result

Comment: And what is your import file structure looking like? Which version of Magento is it for?

Comment: @JulienLachal magento 1.9

Answer (score 0):

// cross check following points.

```
1. check file valid csv extention.
2. Check file size.
3. Present sku column name in file. (lowercase for ex : sku).
4. Best try with 1-2 dummy records and then check.
```

//More Reference link.

[Import data with import/export option](https://trellis.co/blog/uploading-products-magento-product-excel/)

[Import data with dataflow option](https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-exportimport-data-in-csv-files.html#gref)

Comment: Try with few dummy records first.

Comment: can you explain how ?

Comment: Provided reference link for same.